# Umano SlidingUpPanel stucks when swiping from anchor to collapsed state

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, listview, slidingpanelayout

I have created a [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) which consits of google map in top layout and listview in bottom panel.Layout also have an anchor point .The issue I am having is that many times whin i slide panel from anchor point to collapsed state it stucks in between in such a way that I have to slide many times to move from anchor to collapsed state..Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

xml

```
   <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"
        sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/rvOrderHistory"
        sothree:umanoInitialState="anchored"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="110dp"
        sothree:umanoFadeColor="@android:color/transparent"
        >
        <!--xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/maincontent_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/maplayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ren"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ryuh" />
                <include
                    layout="@layout/search_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/uuygu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@drawable/line_divider"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

search_layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/five_dp">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fourty_dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:elevation="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:background="@color/white_transpirancey"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_icon"

        android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray_variant_2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fifteen_sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = getActivity();
        View rootLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.ljg_fragment, null);

        mSlidingLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);

.
.
.
        mSearchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(mContext);
        mSlidingLayout.setAnchorPoint(0.4f);
        mSlidingLayout.setDragView(mListLayout);
        mSlidingLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED);
        height = mMapLayout.getHeight();
        int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
        switch (screenSize) {
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
                mLargeScreen = true;
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
                mLargeScreen = true;
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
                mLargeScreen = false;
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
                mLargeScreen = false;
                break;
            default:
                mLargeScreen = false;
        }

        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
            googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        }
        mSlidingLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) {

                if (newState == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED) {
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(AppPreferences.getLat(mContext)), Double.parseDouble(AppPreferences.getLong(mContext)))));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17), 2000, null);
                    refreshBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 10, refreshIconMargin);
                } else if (newState == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED) {
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(AppPreferences.getLat(mContext)), Double.parseDouble(AppPreferences.getLong(mContext)))));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16), 2000, null);
                    refreshBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 10);
                }
            }
        });
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
         ...
            }
        });
        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

              ....

            }
        });



        searchtaxt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actvAddress.getWindowToken(), 0);
  callXYZApi();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        rvList.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

                        callXYZApi();
                }
                return true; // ONLY if more data is actually being loaded; false otherwise.
            }
        });

        return rootLayout;
    }
```

Log posted according to Aman's answer when moving from anchor to collaped state-

```
06-21 11:39:40.604 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelStateChanged: prevoius state : ANCHORED  new state: DRAGGING
06-21 11:39:40.604 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.3428332
06-21 11:39:40.620 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.27158424
06-21 11:39:40.628 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.25062868
06-21 11:39:40.637 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.21961442
06-21 11:39:40.653 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.16680637
06-21 11:39:40.670 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.122380555
06-21 11:39:40.686 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.08968986
06-21 11:39:40.702 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.064543165
06-21 11:39:40.718 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.04526404
06-21 11:39:40.735 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.030176027
06-21 11:39:40.751 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.020117352
06-21 11:39:40.767 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.012573345
06-21 11:39:40.783 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.0075440067
06-21 11:39:40.800 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.004191115
06-21 11:39:40.816 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.002514669
06-21 11:39:40.832 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 8.38223E-4
06-21 11:39:40.865 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.0
06-21 11:39:40.883 1502-1502/TEST: onPanelStateChanged: prevoius state : DRAGGING  new state: COLLAPSED
```

Log when its stucking

```
onPanelStateChanged: prevoius state : ANCHORED  new state: DRAGGING
06-21 11:48:54.909 7299-7299/TEST: onPanelSlide: 1.0
06-21 11:48:54.909 7299-7299/TEST: onPanelSlide: 0.30511317
06-21 11:48:54.928 7299-7299/TEST: onPanelStateChanged: prevoius state : DRAGGING  new state: ANCHORED
```

Comment: can you post search_layout ?

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe posted.please check in updated question

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and the slidinguppanellayout is working as you wanted from your code.
But if you still can't get the desired result then you can add a PanelSlideListener and implements its method like I have did.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private LinearLayout mListLayout;
private SlidingUpPanelLayout mSlidingLayout;
float slideoffset=1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    mSlidingLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
    mSlidingLayout.setAnchorPoint(0.4f);
    mSlidingLayout.setDragView(mListLayout);
    mSlidingLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
            slideoffset=slideOffset;
            Log.d(TAG, "onPanelSlide: " + slideOffset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPanelStateChanged: prevoius state : " + previousState + "  new state: " + newState);
            if(slideoffset<0.2&&(previousState== SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED||previousState== SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED))
            {
                mSlidingLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

First I am getting the slidingOffset from onPanelSlide method and using this slidingOffset value to determine the current position of slidinguppanellayout so that in onPanelStateChanged method I can use the previous state and slideOffset value to know the set the end state.

> If you still persist problem after this then just post out the logcat.

Comment: Log posted when moving from anchor to collaped state

Comment: and also posted log for when its stucking

Comment: Can you post out the whole class, after that may be I can find out something ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Hope this helps.

```
@Override
    public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
        slideoffset=slideOffset;
    }

@Override    
public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) 
{
            if(slideoffset<0.2&& previousState == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.DRAGGING)
            {
                mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);
            }
            else if(slideoffset == 1&& previousState == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.DRAGGING)
            {
                mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);
            }}
```